# Eclipse Editor does not contain a main type

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm a bit new in Java aka. IDE

[image]

As you can see, there is a Main Method, but it still does not accept it. I tried to rightclick the .java class and run, but still did not work

Thanks!

Comment: Yea, but did not help me

Comment: Right click your `nachhilfe_array_schleifen` folder and go to `Build Path > Use as Source Folder`. Then try again.

Comment: Which source folder are you using? With other words, where is your source folder located?

Comment: @TiiJ7 Thanks, that solved my problem!

Comment: And that is the third answer on the duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right Click project-->Properties-->Java Build Path in source tab add your project src

Comment: This is suitable for a comment.